# sequential autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Consider the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>State/Province</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="country_1" value="" /></td>
        <td><input name="stateProv_1" value="" /></td>
        <td><input name="city_1" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="country_n" value="" /></td>
        <td><input name="stateProv_n" value="" /></td>
        <td><input name="city_n" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

I want to use [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) to help my user enter the data. The value for `country_1` is used to select the possible values for `stateProv_1` is used to select the possible values for `city_1`.

This sort of sequential autocomplete is explained pretty well [by this Q&A](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-parameters-using-jquery-ui-for-autocomplete).

My question concerns the jQuery bit itself: must I dupe the autocomplete code for every single input tag?

```
$( "country_1" ).autocomplete({ ... });
$( "stateProv_1" ).autocomplete({ ... });
$( "city_1" ).autocomplete({ ... });
...
$( "country_n" ).autocomplete({ ... });
$( "stateProv_n" ).autocomplete({ ... });
$( "city_n" ).autocomplete({ ... });
```

Or is there a way for each *type* of autocomplete (Country, StateProv, City) to monitor all its inputs?

**n** is variable depending on the user context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to repeat it for the 3 types, not for 3 types X n times

```
$( 'input[name^="country_"]' ).autocomplete({ ... });
$( 'input[name^="stateProv_"]' ).autocomplete({ ... });
$( 'input[name^="city_"]' ).autocomplete({ ... });
```

You can use the `this.element` inside the source function to do this

Something like

```
$('input[name^="stateProv_"]').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, term){
        console.log(request, this.element);
        var name = this.element.attr('name');
        var idx = name.substring(10);
        var elcountry = $('input[name="country_' +  idx + '"]');
        console.log(idx, 'c', elcountry.val())
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T8j5q/)

Comment: Please see my comment for Dipesh.

Comment: You are using the `source` function isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor all the inputs:

```
$( "input" ).autocomplete({ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class` for `input` and then apply `auto-complete` to `class`.

**HTML**

```
<td><input class="makemeauto" name="country_1" value="" /></td>
<td><input class="makemeauto" name="stateProv_1" value="" /></td>
<td><input class="makemeauto" name="city_1" value="" /></td>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".makemeauto").autocomplete({ ... });
```

**Comment Response**

You need to call `autocomplete` separately for each element:

```
<td><input class="makemeauto" name="country_1" value="" data-autocomplete-source ="source_country"/></td>
<td><input class="makemeauto" name="stateProv_1" value="" data-autocomplete-source ="source_stateProy"/></td>
<td><input class="makemeauto" name="city_1" value="" data-autocomplete-source ="source_city" /></td>


$('input.makemeauto').each(function()
{
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: $(this).data('autocomplete-source')
    });
});
```

Comment: how then do you confine `stateProv_2` 's autocomplete query to only use the value in `country_2` ?

Comment: @AndrewHeath you can use `switch` or `if` to get which `textbox` its currently poiting to and according to that make a `request`.

Comment: ahh, including an extra datum to link each input back to its parent. Clever!

Answer (score 0):

You could have 1 function for updating your autocomplete. Maybe give each type of input a class.

```
<td><input class="country" name="country_n" value="" /></td>
        <td><input class="state" name="stateProv_n" value="" /></td>
        <td><input class="city" name="city_n" value="" /></td>

$(function(){
  $(".country").change(countryChanged);
  $(".state").change(stateChanged);
});

function countryChange(){
  var $countryInput = $(this);
  var $stateInput = $countryInput.parent().next().children(".state");
  $stateInput.autocomplete({});
}
function stateChange(){
  //similar code sequence
}
```

You could also have 1 function with a switch that determines what to do depending on if it is a country or a state etc.